# Prevent giving links of bootstrap CDN in every page of html in my website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website and using bootstrap CDN. The problem is that I have to give bootstrap links in every html page and I want to get rid of it or at least give 1 or 2 links only instead of giving the whole CDN in every page. Is it possible or not? If so then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

@SahilMughal for that you have to convert your page from .html to .php & you also need to cut your header & footer part in different .php page & then include them in your website pages.

Comment: I am building a java ee website how can I achieve this in jsp?

Comment: @SahilMughal in that case you should also mansion that you are making the website in java. How u can suppose someone gets already know that you are making in java.